# MonoTorrent how to process only specified files

Tags: c#, monotorrent

I want to download only specified file from torrent using MonoTorrent.

I use `TorrentFile.Priority = Priority.DoNotDownload;` , with this MonoTorrent doesn't download useless files for me, but MonoTorrent creates fake clear file, how can i avoid it? How can i avoid creation of fake mirror files for files with `DoNowDownload` priority?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid it is to exclude that file from initial torrent file. That is protocol specific problem - fake files used to count pices hash.